# Cube Scape seat creaking

Tags: saddle

Having some problems with my seat. I have a Cube Analog Disc 2012 bike. After only 100km, the seat started creaking. I sent it back to the shop and received a brand new seat instead. But unfortunately, after another ~200km, the seats started creaking softly, but I believe that in a few days, the irritating creak from the first seat will come back.

It's worth mentioning, that the creak comes from right under the seat, from the plastic that sustains the fabric; right between the front and rear supporting points. Also, I have only 66kg, so weight is not the problem.

I've included a photo so things would be clearer.

[image: picture]

Has anyone stumbled upon this issue? What should I do? I believe it's not a solution sending the seat back for replacement once every two weeks...

Comment: Lots of seats creak.  It's a little unusual for one without springs to creak very loudly, but keep in mind that as the seat flexes under your weight the layers of the cover and pad slide against each other slightly, and this could lead to squeaks.  In addition, the joints where the rails connect to the plastic base may experience some motion and may squeak.  This doesn't indicate that anything serious is wrong with the seat.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But still, the creak is a little bit annoying, it shouldn't be there. And I expect this thing from a Cube bike which wasn't very cheap. Is there anything to "fix" regarding that cover?

Comment: On the off chance that the creak is coming from the rail/base connections you could put a drop of silicone oil in each.  Not much you can do if the creak is between the layers of the seat, other than to get a different brand.

Comment: I have a fracture of this type of seat :-D (my weight is only 72kg) and 1mm overhang of furrow made by holder causes rejection of my claim. Bad luck or my stupidity. :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's unlikely that the issue is the seat itself.

In 99 cases out of 100, the issue is that seat clamp at the top of the post that holds the saddle rails is loose, or wearing.  Usually loose.

Grab your set of allen keys, find the 5mm or 6mm which will fit the 2 bolt there, and tighten them up to about 10-12 Nm. If it still creaks, consider replacing the post, but it shouldn't come to that.

Comment: I've tested the seat when I sent it for replacement, and it did creak. Since it was only the seat (not attached to the seat post nor any other part), it should have been the seat. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If that's the case, you'll need to replace the seat with something of much better quality.

Comment: But shouldn't Scape saddles be of some kind of quality? After all, we're talking about a Cube bicycle...My first bike was kind of no name and I had no problems with the saddle for more than 2 years.

Comment: Most bicycle brands, regardless of quality of the bike, use a saddle which is very basic, because saddles are very personal. If they use an expensive saddle, they increase the cost of the bike for something you have about a 1 in 10 chance of really fitting you well. It makes better economic sense to use a basic saddle, and just know you will pick something of quality later, for yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer. The bad thing is that I really like this seat, it both looks good and feels very comfortable. Unfortunately, the creak ruins it all...

Answer (score 0):

buy a better seat, I have a CUBE Agree and needed a seat upgrade, a good quality, comfortable seat is an important upgrade as a rider gets more serious on any bike. Look at specialist manufacturers and web forums on this issue, it will narrow down a lot your choices. I now have a '2012 Fizik Aliante VS'.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Will consider buying a new seat.